# DSolve seems to give a wrong solution

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica so I started out with a rather simple differential equation that can be solved by hand:

$y'(t) = k1*S - k2*y(t)$

**1)** My input:

```
DSolve[y'[t] == k1*S - k2*y[t], y[t], t]
```

> {{y[t] -> (k1 S)/k2 + E^(-k2 t) C[1]}}

**2)** Also, When I tried to add boundary `y[0] == 0` it completely doesn't understand the input.

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == k1*S - k2*y[t], y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
```

***My issue is I can't seem to fix it with rewriting my equation in different ways. Is it an inherent issue with Mathematica 11. Others said the input I used should work! Please help!***

Comment: 1) is correct; 2) the input should be`DSolve[{y'[t] == k1*S - k2*y[t], y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]`.

Comment: `DSolve[{y'[t] == k1*S - k2*y[t], y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]` works fine, the answer seems correct to me: `(k1*S - k2*y[t]) /. s // Simplify` gives the same as `D[(y[t] /. s), t]`

Comment: Thanks. But I still get the no interpretation available for input DSolve[{y'[t] == k1*S - k2*y[t], y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]

Comment: Try starting with a fresh kernel.

Comment: @BobHanlon: A very naive question: how can I start with a fresh kernel? I tried "quit" and it s still not working with the boundary conditions

Comment: @BobHanlon I found it! it works! Thank you :)

Comment: I use the menu command `Evaluation | Quit Kernel | Local`

Comment: It actually didn't work. It works with other equation than doesn't involve the form y'[t] == y[t] though. Could it be a bug on Mathematica 11.0?

Comment: What does `DSolve[{y'[t] == k1*S - k2*y[t], y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]` return for you. I get a result using version 11.0.1 under Windows 10.